# How to customize yii2 gridview filter row?

Tags: gridview, yii2-advanced-app, datagridviewcolumn

```
                <?=
                    GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'filterModel' => $searchModel,                            
                        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table custom-table-view table-striped table-bordered'],
                        'columns' => [
                            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                            [
                                'label' => 'User name',
                                'attribute' => 'name',
                                'filterInputOptions' => [
                                    'class' => 'form-control custom-form-control pr-5',
                                    'placeholder' => 'Search...',
                                   
                                ],
                                
                            ],
                        ],
                    ])
                    ?>
```

This is the code which I am using, using this code I am able to add class into and this is the out put.

```
<table class="table custom-table-view table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr id="w0-filters" class="filters">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="search-name" class="form-control custom-form-control pr-5" name="Search[name]" placeholder="Search..."></td>
     </tr>
```

But what I want is

```
<tr id="w0-filters" class="filters">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>
    <div class"my_class">
    <input type="text" id="search-name" class="form-control custom-form-control pr-5" name="Search[name]" placeholder="Search..."><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </div>
</td>
```

How to add my_class div outside input field.?

Answer (score 0):

Question is: why would you want to do that? To me it sounds like you are looking for the GridView afterHeader function.

IF you really need something like that, you would have to extend GridView class and overwrite renderFilters().

```
<?php

namespace app\common\override\yii2;

class GridView extends \kartik\grid\GridView
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function renderFilters()
    {
        /* Just send the Original Filter for demonstration */
        return parent::renderFilters();
    }
}
```

You will find the original renderFilters function just returns a string:

```
return Html::tag('tr', implode('', $cells), $this->filterRowOptions);
```

Best strategy to alter the string may be to change the renderFilterCell() function, simpler approach could be

```
$cells[] = Html::tag('div',$column->renderFilterCell(),['class'=>'my_class']);
```